# Can I use same Raspbian Arm v7 installation on Intel Q7450 CPU?

Tags: raspbian

I have a B3+ PI running Raspbian Buster x32 on a armv7 cpu. I have made extensive customizations on this installations and I am wondering if I can use the same installation on a different x86 machine with an Intel Q9450 CPU without making all the configuration all over again for my software and network. I understand that several modifications may be needed to transfer the installation from the sdcard to a hard drive, but that is acceptable.

Is this possible due to the differences between the instruction sets and architecture of the two CPUs?

I've done some research on the internet but not found much substantial info on this.

Comment: You can't run ARM binaries on an x86 cpu. Could you not make the same 'customizations' to an x86 Debian Buster installation?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey as I have mentioned I have made extensive customizations and comfigurations on network, iptables, users, services and that's just for the system. Not to mention the changes made for the software I use. It's been a ongoing work for about 1 and a half year now and I have not track all of the changes. Is there any other way? Export the config for network, services f.i. or make an iso or something that I can use with x86 and keep the changes?